# Content by Query Webpart returning Results twice

Tags: caml-query, content-query-web-part

I am instantiation a content by query webpart from code.

I am overwriting the CAML Query. As soon as my query contains a managed metadata filter all results are returned twice.

**My query looks like this:**

```
<Where><And><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value  Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0101</Value></BeginsWith><In><FieldRef LookupId='True' Name='Schlagworte' /><Values><Value Type='Integer'>624</Value></Values></In></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>
```

I searched the web but couldn't find any information on it. Any Ideas, what could cause this error?

Thanks in advance!
Max